# Ценообразование в 1С по формуле

Tags: 1с

Как задать расчёт цен по формуле в справочнике вид цен (1С УТ11.4)? Своими руками не получается, не знаю синтаксиса. Необходимо чтобы цены рассчитывались по формуле в зависимости от вида цен «Розничная» для вида цен «Зачеркнутая»:

- Если вид цены «Розничная» меньше или равно 100, то вид цены       «Зачёркнутая» + 30%
- Если вид цены «Розничная» больше 101 и меньше или равно 500, то виды цены «Зачёркнутая» + 15%
- Если вид цены «Розничная» больше 501, то виды цены «Зачёркнутая» + 5%

Формула нужна для внесения в справочник ценообразования - Виды цен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Создаем новый вид цены:

[image: Создание вида цены]

2) Нажимаем "Использовать полные возможности":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Указываем **Способ задания цены** - *Произвольная формула от других видов цен*

Сама формула будет такой:

?([Розничная] <= 100, [Розничная] + ([Розничная] * 0.30), ?([Розничная] > 101 И [Розничная] <= 500, [Розничная]+([Розничная]*0.15), [Розничная]+([Розничная]*0.05)) )